# Combine two select

Tags: sql, sql-server, dml

I have the following table

*test*

```
+----+---------+------+
| Id | NumFact | type |
+----+---------+------+
| 1  |   20    |  A   |
| 2  |   21    |  A   |
| 3  |   22    |  A   |
| 4  |   23    |  B   |
| 5  |   24    |  B   |
| 6  |   25    |  B   | 
| 7  |   26    |  B   |
| 8  |   26    |  T   |
+----+---------+------+
```

I need to get the following result , get the number of NumFact  for only A and B

*Expected Result*

```
+------+--------+
| Num  |   type |
+------+--------+
|  3   |    A   |
|  4   |    B   |
+------+--------+
```

I wrote the following *queries*.

```
     -- select query 1 --
    Select (count NumFact  )as Num 
    from test 
    where type = 'A' 

     -- select query 2 --
    Select (count NumFact  )as Num 
    from test 
    where type = 'B'
```

How can I make only one *select* and get *Num*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to group by `type` and filter properly.

```
SELECT type, COUNT(NumFact) AS Num
FROM test
WHERE type IN ('A','B')
GROUP BY type;
```

What this says is to group the result set the column `type` and use the aggregate function `COUNT()` for each group but only where the `type` column value is equal to 'A' or 'B'.

It is pretty basic SQL really. Read more about [GROUP BY on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms177673.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Use `GROUP BY`

### **Query1**

```
SELECT COUNT(NumFact) AS Num,
type FROM test
WHERE type IN ('A','B')
GROUP BY type
```

### **Query2**

```
SELECT COUNT(NumFact) AS Num,
type FROM test
WHERE type='A' OR type='B'
GROUP BY type;
```

---

### [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ecb44/5)

Answer (score 2):

Or a slightly different version:

```
SELECT COUNT(NumFact) AS Num, Type
FROM test
GROUP BY Type
HAVING (Type = 'A') OR (Type = 'B')
```

Comment: `HAVING (Type = 'A') OR (Type = 'B')` is a bad idea

Comment: Why so? ...just interested.

Comment: with my experience  : `HAVING type IN ('A','B')` is better than `HAVING (Type = 'A') OR (Type = 'B')`

Comment: I'm guessing that the main reason it may be better is that you can then have a further SELECT clause within the brackets if there is to be a dynamic filter.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
   type,count(numfact) as num
from  test 
group by type 
order by type
```

--OR--

```
select 
   type,count(numfact) as num 
from  test 
where type in('A','B')
group by type 
order by type
```

Comment: I dont think that an explanation is needed for this OP can understand when he run the select there nothing complex in that select